# Haskell: How to update each infinite variable once in list comprehension using infinite lists

Tags: list, haskell, list-comprehension

If I've got something that looks like this:

```
list1 = [(a,b,c) | a <- [0..], b <- [0..], c <- [0..]]
```

How would I go about updating each of the variables once instead of c infinitely growing?

Like this:

```
[(0,0,0), (0,0,1), (0,1,1), (1,1,1), ...]
```

Instead of this:

```
[(0,0,0), (0,0,1), (0,0,2), (0,0,3), ...]
```

Comment: Check out [`Control.Monad.Omega`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/control-monad-omega-0.3.1/docs/Control-Monad-Omega.html)

Comment: (I know the first few answers at the linked dupe don't meet your "multiple infinite lists" criteria. Just keep reading. I promise there's an answer that does.)